# R - Issue with using the package brandwatchR

Tags: r, encoding

So I am using an R package (brandwatchR) to connect to the Brandwatch API. Works fairly well for the most part.

My issue is that when exporting the data, it messes up (I'm assuming) the encoding for certain dates, and I get a lot of NA values for twitter mentions (does not happen for the other ones).

Code I use below

```
library(brandwatchR)
my_mentions <- bwr_mentions_get(
  project_id = project_ID,
  query_id = Query_ID,
  date_range = c(Sys.Date() - 5, Sys.Date() - 1))
```

The only message I do get is this one :
**No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.**

And this does not result in an error or anything but this is what leads me to assume it's an encoding issue.

And the weird thing is it's only Twitter mentions that have problems. So if anyone worked with this package before would appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance